# Drupal 7: Saving images or other content to the user profile page

Tags: drupal-7, user-profile

This is a Drupal 7 question. I want the ability for an authenticated user to be able to save an image or a piece of content to their user profile page. This option should be able to be used with a 'save' button while browsing a photo gallery.....and will be readily available for the user to go back to and see what they have saved in their user profile. What is the best way to do this? Thanks for the help.

-James

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be able to add pictures/images to the user profile page, then you can take a look at the [Register with Pic](https://drupal.org/project/reg_with_pic) module. Also, this link might also be helpful-

https://drupal.org/node/22271

Comment: Thanks, Shekhar. I think I am talking about something a little bit different. I want a signed in user to have the ability to save an image (that is being displayed in some kind of slideshow or gallery)....and have it appear on that users profile page. So the image will be on the same site, maybe added by another user or the site admin......and then any other user would be able to click a save button and have it added to their own profile.......that image being saved (when being saved to the users profile) should have a link that returns you to the gallery from which you saved it. Thanks, James